# explain the chrome performance tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

look at the screenshot.As what I know the DOM render will be block when the javascript is running. Why the performance tool show that the html parse and evaluate script **run parallel**

Comment: It shows you the BREAKDOWN of that call. The whole chunk of time is the `Parse HTML` but that is merely the top level function, each other called *by* it is below. Essentially if you have `function top() { partOne(); partTwo() }` then performance can show you that, say, `top` took 800ms to complete but the next line will detail that `partOne` was 300ms and `partTwo` was 500ms. Each subsequent line would then show how much each function called by the above took.

Comment: So you mean that parse html incloude the evaluate script?

Comment: Yes, it appears that's what is happening. Each thing could then go through various other hooks.